# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

Using python to try and make table:

```
nameTable = (str(site[i])[32:])
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE (?)(id INTEGER, Topics TEXT)''', (str(nameTable)))
```

When running the code, I get the following error:

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE (?)(id INTEGER, Topics TEXT)''', (str(nameTable)))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: You can't use sql parameters to insert tables; the whole point of sql parameters is to avoid allowing sql objects to be produced.

Comment: You cannot use a placeholder for table name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323739/placeholder-for-table-name